# How can you color a specific edge in R igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a nodes and edges list that I used to create a network object in igraph.

The edges list has a column for 'color' of edges.  But this column is being ignored when I plot the network object. All my edges are gray (default).  How can I make sure in the plot function that it takes into account the column titled 'color' OR how can I just specify a color for a specific edge.

Why isn't edge.color=c(1,7, "red") working within the plot function?

Answer (score 0):

you can color to specific edge using below. code.

```
E(g)[1]$color = "red"
```

here, g is the graph and color is set to